# Roboearth installation in fuerte in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Who can provide a web link to tell me how to install  Roboearth  in fuerte in ubuntu 12.04???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43774/roboearth-installation-in-fuerte-in-ubuntu-12.04/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-13**:
I'm not sure if Roboearth already has been ported to Fuerte. But please retag your question to help people who can help find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Write these commands in the terminal :

rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/fuerte 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'

$ source ~/ros/setup.bash

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ias-common ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo ros-fuerte-vision-opencv ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping ros-fuerte-client-rosjava-jni.

rosmake roboearth

---

Originally posted by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) with karma: 238 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-08**:
ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons does not exist in Ubuntu 12.04, should this be ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable? This doesn't work for me, unfortunately.